# How to compact files in a single file when memory is limited?

Tags: xml, json, stream, streaming, large-files

I assume that this will be possible with the help of **streams**, but how exactly?

My best guess at the moment is to use a library either for **Json** or for **Xml**.

Currently, there are libraries and I've seen tutorials that can parse and write json/xml very efficiently using only one element at a time (i.e. https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming)

The main issue is that there are not that many elements in my final `json/xml` but the values of my elements are quite large!

Imagine taking a entire file and encoding it somehow into a string so that you could have a `json` with an element like that: `"file1": "AAFA252265VFAAAAER............"` *<--- this string is too long for current available memory*

Answer (score 0):

Ok no worries I found the solution and I am sharing it here.

Well **GSON** is open source therefore you could see how it works underneath.
There are multiple methods to write a json value but none of them works with a stream.
In other words GSON library it self writes on a stream but there is no such a method as `writer.value(stream)`

**Solutions**:

***More elegant***: One way of course is that you could override a method or just copy paste an entire method and write a new one your own.

***Dummy but quicker***: Create a **Json array**. So instead of writing a single json string you write multiple json strings that belong to an array. The length of each string is of course depends on how much memory you have available!
Reading this array string by string with GSON reader recreates the file.

*Note: you must use some sort of encoding to write a file into a string*